# Attributes of products in cart in opencart

Tags: attributes, customization, opencart, cart

I am rather new to opencart and I'm currently developing a shop where I need to be able to display product attributes inside the cart. I searched allover but apparently no one had the need for this feature.
I short, i tried to duplicate the way attributes are retrieved in the product page but no success.
I modified the controller adding this line:

```
$this->data['attribute_groups'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($this->request->get['product_id']);
```

I also added:

```
<?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { ?>
  <?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?>
    <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
   <?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>
<?php echo $attribute['text']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

with no succes.
I guess I have to modify somehow system/library/cart.php. The problem is that I am not savvy enough to know how to do it!
At this point I decided to ask for help here!
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as hard as it would seem on the surface you'll only need to edit 2 files and open 3.

--1-- Add the method for retrieving attributes to the cart class.

Open catalog/model/catalog/product.php

Find the method `getProductAttributes($product_id)` and copy the entire method to your clipboard.

Open `system/library/cart.php` and after the `getProducts()` method paste your copied method.

--2-- Just above where you pasted the code, at the end of the `getProducts()` method you'll see where the products array is built for the view, it looks similar to this:

```
$this->data[$key] = array(
    'key'             => $key,
    'product_id'      => $product_query->row['product_id'],
    'name'            => $product_query->row['name'],
    'model'           => $product_query->row['model'],
    'shipping'        => $product_query->row['shipping'],
    'image'           => $product_query->row['image'],
    'option'          => $option_data,
    'download'        => $download_data,
    'quantity'        => $quantity,
    'minimum'         => $product_query->row['minimum'],
    'subtract'        => $product_query->row['subtract'],
    'stock'           => $stock,
    'price'           => ($price + $option_price),
    'total'           => ($price + $option_price) * $quantity,
    'reward'          => $reward * $quantity,
    'points'          => ($product_query->row['points'] ? ($product_query->row['points'] + $option_points) * $quantity : 0),
    'tax_class_id'    => $product_query->row['tax_class_id'],
    'weight'          => ($product_query->row['weight'] + $option_weight) * $quantity,
    'weight_class_id' => $product_query->row['weight_class_id'],
    'length'          => $product_query->row['length'],
    'width'           => $product_query->row['width'],
    'height'          => $product_query->row['height'],
    'length_class_id' => $product_query->row['length_class_id']                 
);
```

Now simply add a call to that getAttributes method to the array:

`'attributes'     => $this->getProductAttributes($product_query->row['product_id'])`

Now open your cart template: `catalog/view/theme/yourtheme/common/cart.tpl` and right where the product option loop is, you can now loop through your attributes just like the options.

Comment: Still, no data showing up in cart. Do I have to modify the controller also? Thank you again!

Comment: I'd say yes, sorry about that.  I didn't realize that the cart controller was creating a new array for the cart display.  Take a look in the controller where the `$this->data['products'][] = array(` is being built. Right above you'll see the creation of the `$option_data` array ...  you should be able to use that as an example on how to format and add your attributes.